# In a function call, what is the operator, and what are the operands?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, kernighan-and-ritchie, function-call-operator

I am trying to understand some basics of C. KRC's The C Programming Language says

> **A function call is a postfix expression**, called the function designator, followed by parentheses containing  a  possibly  empty,  comma-separated  list  of  assignment  expressions  (Par.A7.17), 
>   which  constitute  the  arguments  to  the  function.

1. In a function call, what is the operator, and what are the operands?

   Is `()` the operator?

   Is the function name an operand?

   Are the arguments inside `()` operands?
2. Is a function designator a synonym of a function call?

Thanks.

Comment: Function call is defined in the yellow box, and it is obviously *not* the function designator, which is the function name.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a function call, `()` is an operator just like `[]` is an operator when accessing an array element.

6.5.2 Postfix operators

> ```
> Syntax
> 1 postfix-expression:
> primary-expression
> postfix-expression [ expression ]
> postfix-expression ( argument-expression-listopt )
> postfix-expression . identifier
> postfix-expression -> identifier
> postfix-expression ++
> postfix-expression --
> ( type-name ) { initializer-list }
> ( type-name ) { initializer-list , }
>
> argument-expression-list:
> assignment-expression
> argument-expression-list , assignment-expression
> ```

Operand for this operator is the function name (or a pointer to the function).

> Are the arguments inside `()` operands?

No. As per the C standard the list of expressions specifies the arguments to the function.

Comment: formal grammar definition is definitely what the beginners need the most :)

Comment: *operand* is essentially a synonym of *argument*. -- *[An operand, then, is also referred to as "one of the inputs (quantities) for an operation".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand)*

Comment: @PeterJ, perhaps, but the OP has a rep of 23K, hardly a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

The text in the C standard is nearly identical, 6.5.2.2:

> A postfix expression followed by parentheses () containing a possibly
>   empty, comma-separated list of expressions is a function call. The
>   postfix expression denotes the called function. The list of
>   expressions specifies the arguments to the function.

The syntax is (6.5.2):

```
postfix-expression ( argument-expression-listopt )
```

This means that the function name is a "postfix-expression" and the `( )` is the actual operator. The C standard does not speak of operands for this operator, but I suppose you could call the function name an operand. The argument list is not an operand, but rather a special case.

---

The definition of a function designator is (6.3.2.1):

> A *function designator* is an expression that has function type.

Meaning in the expression `func();`, `func` would be the function designator but the expression as whole would be a function call. So it is not exactly the same term.

Consider the example `funcptr_t f = func;` which involves the function designator `func` but no function call.

Comment: Btw, knowing these things is pretty much useless knowledge to anyone who isn't writing a compiler.

Comment: *I suppose you could call the function name an operand.*  This is not common practice: the word *operand* in the context of a function call more often designates each of the expressions in the argument list, a synonym for argument.  The C Standard does not use *operand* for this, nor for macro arguments or parameters, but specifications for other programming languages do, such as Python.

Comment: @chqrlie Hence the "I suppose" :) I did emphasize that the standard does not mention any operands in this case.

Comment: Note §6.5.2.2 ¶1 says: _The expression that denotes the called function (92) shall have type pointer to function
returning void or returning a complete object type other than an array type._  Footnote 92 says: _Most often, this is the result of converting an identifier that is a function designator._  And §6.3.2.1 continues: _Except when it is the
operand of the sizeof operator,(65) or the unary & operator, a function designator with
type ‘‘function returning type’’ is converted to an expression that has type ‘‘pointer to function returning type"._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: there is no question a function designator can be used as the operand of some operators, that does not make it the operand of the function call operator, which is not designated as such either.