# What is the part of a full-expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider this example

```cpp
#include <iostream>
struct A{
   A(){
       std::cout<<"A ctor\n";
   }
   ~A(){
       std::cout<<"A dtor\n";
   }
};
int fun(A const&){
    std::cout<<"abc\n";
    return 0;
}
void show(double, int){
    std::cout<<"show\n";
}
int main() {
   show(0,fun(A{}));  // #1
}
```

According to the [result](https://godbolt.org/z/ohGGn9dd9), it is observable that the temporary object is destroyed at the completion of `#1`. According to [class.temporary] p6

> The exceptions to this lifetime rule are:
>
> > - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call ([expr.call]) persists **until the completion of the full-expression containing the call**.

I wonder why is `show(0,fun(A{}));`  the full-expression of `fun(A{})`? According to [basic.exec#intro.execution-5]

> A full-expression is
>
> > -[...]
> >
> > - an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part of a full-expression.

`show(0,fun(A{}));` is a full-expression, however, the function call `fun(A{})` that is an argument of the function call of `show` is not a subexpression of the enclosing function call(if explicitly specified arguments are not operands of a function call). The definition of *part of a full-expression* is also not clear in the standard.

I have the following concerns:

- Are arguments considered to be operands of the function call?

> the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45615818/in-a-function-call-what-is-the-operator-and-what-are-the-operands) in C standard seems to say they are not

- What is the part of a full-expression?

Comment: @Scheff'sCat  I didn't ask whether a function call is an expression or not. The answer is it is an expression. I'm asking whether the **arguments** of a function call are **operands** of that function call(**expression**), which determines whether arguments are subexpressions of that function call, which in turn, determines whether an expression is a full-expression or not.

Comment: Sorry, I should've kept my fingers... In practice the full expression ends where the semicolon appears. That might be not be fully correct but works in daily business. :-( I found "an expression... ...that is not otherwise part of a full-expression" quite clear.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat That may be an informal explanation of **full-expression**. I'm looking forward to the formal explanation of **part of a full-expression** as well as whether the arguments are operands.

Comment: But the Standard is written in natural language. At some point it must defer to common sense and understanding of the written words. If every phrase or word needs a formal definition, it would never find an end. "Not a sub-expression of another expression" is as formal as it can get.

Comment: @j6t It is exactly asking whether an argument of a function call is the operand of that expression, which determines whether the argument is a subexpression of that function call. Again, how do you understand the phrase "part of a full-expression"?

Comment: But of course there is no "separation" of expressions between the function call and its arguments. Look at the syntax definition: a function call is a *postfix-expression*, and that is reachable from and recurses into an *expression*.

Comment: Considering that a function call is an Id expression followed by a postfix operator, I don't see why the post-fix operator (the brackets with optional operands separated by commas) should be considered different from any other operator (except for its specific semantic like any other operator).

Comment: _5.2.2: A function call is a postfix expression followed by parentheses containing a possibly empty, comma-separated
list of initializer-clauses which constitute the arguments to the function._ (from N3797) Next step: What are "initializer-clauses"? AFAIS in _8.5. Initializers_, it's part of a recursive definition which boils down to expressions in all cases (if not empty).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Yes, arguments are indeed **expressions**, however, **subexpression** has an explicit specification, which is defined in [basic.exec#intro.execution-3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.exec#intro.execution-3). To be a subexpression, it shall satisfy one bullet in that list.

Comment: I found arguments at the beginning in _1.3. Terms and definitions_. Looking for "operand" I ended up in a Note: which comes directly after your 2nd citation: _Note: in some contexts, such as unevaluated operands, a syntactic subexpression is considered a full-expression (Clause 5). —end
note ]_ I give up...

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Although it is irrelevant with this question, I have to say Isn't that note covered by [basic.exec#intro.execution-5.1]? *A full-expression is an unevaluated operand,*

Comment: The arguments of a function call expression are operands. I'm not sure why you think they aren't. We should interpret the standard in a way that makes sense, instead of going out of our way to use definitions of words that make the standard seem absurd.